# Representation of transparent color in a color picker without confusion with white color

Tags: color, transparency, picker

I have a color picker to choose the background color of a rectangle in a Figma-like editor.

One of the colors is *white rgba(255,255,255,1)*, and another one is *transparent rgba(0,0,0,0)*.

On the image below, the right-most color choice is transparent, and the one just before is white.

[image]

**Question :**
How to represent the *transparent* color so that there is *no confusion* with the *white* color ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If transparent color means *no color* the representation is a red diagonal or cross:

[image: cross]

If the transparent color is an area, the representation is a simulation of a gray grid:

[image]

Comment: ah nice ! I like the gray grid, thanks !